# How can I make my house boat move with command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a house boat built on water, and want to make it move around using Command Blocks.

[image]

[More pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4RbS.jpg).

What Command Block setup would I need to move the boat in four cardinal directions?

Comment: Closing an older question as a duplicate of a newer question because that one has a proper answer whereas this one has only a vague answer and a bunch of ugly hacks.

Answer (score 1):

Some working on the [/clone](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#clone) command of version 1.8 alongside /tp-ing the player may be your best bet. However, I'm unsure how you would get the previous boat to dissappear to hack a sort of movement. The tools just aren't there without mods from my understanding at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

A more primitive and time-consuming solution:

Store all of the block datas into command blocks with /setblock and add a /tp for yourself, then wire it up with a redstone clock. Stand in the boat. In the /setblock commands, use tilde notation so it creates a new boat relative to the location of the old.

Restore the blocks in the old location to those of the environment before the boat (e.g. a block of the hull will be replaced by a block water) using /setblock.

Simeaultaneously /tp yourself and /setblock the new boat a few blocks in the direction you want to go relative to the previous location.

Hope this helps!
(apologies for the verbosity)

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the entire thing on minecarts (using /summon) and have the minecarts move using /execute @e[type=Minecart] tp @e[type=Minecart] ~ ~ ~1 Its a bit complicated, only works in the snapshot

Answer (score 0):

You could use the /fill to replace the area that you want your boat to go to and again use /fill to fill the area that the boat used to be in with area. If you wanted to move yourself as we'll use /tp to move you along with the boat.